# Finding a minimum of a function, measuring the sum of the squares of distance from some points of the $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Given are a finite number of points $a_1, ..., a_m \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Consider the sum of the squares of distance:

$$f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^m ||x-a_k||^2, x \in \mathbb{R}^n$$

with $||.||$ being the Euclidian norm.

I first want to prove that $f$ has one but only one local minimum $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and want to find it.

Finally, I want to prove that $x_0$ is also a global maximum.

My approach so far was to try to differentiate $f$. For $x = (x_1, ..., x_n), a_k = (a_{1k}, ..., a_{nk}) \in \mathbb{R}^n$, we would get:

$$f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^m ||x-a_k||^2 = \sum_{k=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n (x_j - a_{jk})^2 = \sum_{k=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n (x_j^2 - 2x_j a_{jk} + a_{jk}^2) \\ = (x_1^2 - 2 x_1 a_{11} + a_{11}^2) + ... + (x_n^2 - 2 x_1 a_{n1} + a_{n1}^2) + ... + (x_1^2 - 2 x_1 a_{1m} + a_{1m}^2) + ... + (x_n^2 - 2 x_1 a_{nm} + a_{nm}^2)$$

and therefore, I would get that

$$\nabla f(x) = \pmatrix{2x_1 - 2a_{11} + ... + 2x_1 - 2 a_{1m} \\ .. \\ 2x_n - 2a_{n1} + ... + 2x_n - 2 a_{nm}} = \pmatrix{2m x_1 - \sum_{k=1}^m 2a_{1k} \\ ... \\ 2m x_n - \sum_{k=1}^m 2 a_{nk}}$$

and therefore, it would appear that $x_0 = (\sum_{k=1}^m a_{1k}, ..., \sum_{k=1}^m a_{nk})$ would be a candidate for a local minimum because that's where $f'(x) = 0$ (and it would be the only candidate, so there can only be one). Would this be correct so far?

To show that it *is* a local minimum, I would either need to find a neighborhood $U_{x_0} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ of $x_0$, so that $\forall x \in U_{x_0}$, we have that $f(x) ≥ f(x_0)$, or I would need to show that the Hesse matrix $H_f(x_0)$ is positive definite, would I?

I've skipped this for now, because I've been thinking more about how to show that $x_0$ is also a global maximum. Would it be sufficient to show that $lim_{||x|| \to \infty} f(x) = \infty$? Intuitively, it's obvious that that's the case, because the further we move away from $x_0$, the bigger the squares of distance described by this function "will grow". So if we just "move away far enough" from $x_0$, we would know that $f(x)$ would definitely become larger than $f(x_0)$, hence if $x_0$ would not be a global minimum, there would need to be another minimum, which we know there isn't.

I don't really know how to mathematically justify that, so if anyone could come up with a better solution for the second part, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computation of $x_0$ is correct, except that you forgot to divide through $m$ in the end. ($x_0$ is the center of gravity of the $a_k$.)

The argument that $\lim_{|x|\to\infty} f(x)=\infty$ is correct. Then you can, for example, argue that for a sufficiently large radius $r$, the function $f$ restricted to the closed ball of radius $r$ around $0$ has a global minimum and this must also be the global minimum of $f$. Then it obviously is a local minimum too, so you don't need to prove that part again.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are dealing with a moment of inertia, the claim just follows from the [Huygens-Steiner/parallel axis theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_axis_theorem): the absolute minimum is attained by the centroid of $\{a_1,\ldots,a_m\}$.

On the other hand, your argument is perfectly fine, but you do not need to compute any Hessian matrix, since the moment of inertia is a convex function as a sum of convex functions, hence it may have only a global minimum.